# Report .NET Core XUnit tests through Cake build script so that Azure DevOps can use it

Tags: xml, .net-core, azure-devops, xunit.net, cakebuild

I am trying to report the XUnit results of the .NET Core XUnit project in Azure DevOps. The build process is written in a Cake Build script which is called by the Azure DevOps build pipeline. The XUnit tests run, but they are only reporting the bare minimum to the CLI. I want summary and details written to a file: JSON, XML, it doesn't matter too much. Here is sample code currently:

```
Task("UnitTests")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        DotNetCoreTest(
            testProject,
            new DotNetCoreTestSettings()
            {
                Configuration = configuration,
                NoBuild = true
            }
        );
    });
```

The Cake script is being run by the Powershell script though a Powershell task in the Build Pipeline.

What do I have to do to run dotnetcoretest in Cake to make it report out to a format and location that I can use Azure DevOps? I tried using the "-xml" argument and that did not work for dotnet test.

Do I have to add a task in the Build Pipeline in Azure DevOps to grab the XUnit results from the Cake script?

How do I view the XUnit tests in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export in a VSTest format

```
Task("UnitTests")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        DotNetCoreTest(
            testProject,
            new DotNetCoreTestSettings()
            {
                Configuration = configuration,
                NoBuild = true,
                NoRestore = true,
                ArgumentCustomization = args=>args.Append($"--logger trx;LogFileName=\"{testResultsFile}\"")
            }
        );
    });
```

Then you can either add a task in Azure DevOps similar

#### YAML

```
    steps:
    - task: PublishTestResults@2
      displayName: 'Publish Test Results artifacts/**/test-results/*TestResults*.xml'
      inputs:
        testResultsFormat: VSTest
        testResultsFiles: 'artifacts/**/test-results/*TestResults*.xml'
```

#### Designer

[image: Azure Pipelines publish test results task]

#### Cake

Or straight from Cake script use [TFBuild.Commands.PublishTestResults(TFBuildPublishTestResultsData)](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.TFBuild/ITFBuildCommands/9170B98A)

```
TFBuild.Commands.PublishTestResults(
    new TFBuildPublishTestResultsData {
        TestResultsFiles = new []{
            testResultsFile
        },
        TestRunner = TFTestRunnerType.VSTest
    }
)
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, I used the Cake method to publish test results and that worked well.